# Solr search with Mysql Database, any utility for data importing

Tags: mysql, search, solr, lucene

We are looking at ways of improving "search" functionality in our large business application which currently uses SQL Like syntax to do it. So we started evaluating Solr server and were able to index few of our database tables and search. But I am newbie and wanted to know if

1) We have large number of tables in our application. Is there any utility that generates schema xml in solr using the database tables?

<strike>2) Our current search lists the database row that meets the search criteria (this was written using SQL 'like' and takes lot of time to generate the search results). We want to simulate the exact functionality using solr. Is that possible?</strike>

Comment: Confused on what your asking with #2.  The way I read it, you want to search, and get the records that match the query.  Of course, it does that, but I'd assume you would've guessed that.

Comment: ok I think I figured out after analyzing the query syntax and results. So I have updated the question.

Answer (score 1):

For importing a database into SOLR, you might want to look into [DataImportHandler](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DataImportHandler).

There will be a fair amount of configuration required for it, defining what tables and columns to import, what should be stored, and how it should be indexed.