# Apache solr + mysql connection

Tags: mysql, solr, full-text-search

I work on a project. I want to use mysql for storage all data  and solr for search only a string in database. Is it possible ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Solr search with Mysql Database, any utility for data importing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15681577/solr-search-with-mysql-database-any-utility-for-data-importing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's relatively easy. You should look at:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Uploading+Structured+Data+Store+Data+with+the+Data+Import+Handler

and:

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DIHQuickStart

A quick google and I found this gist:

https://gist.github.com/maxivak/3e3ee1fca32f3949f052

which looks pretty reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

I had used it in my application. Only difference is... I have used Oracle database.
For more information check this blog

https://abhijitbashetti.blogspot.com/b/post-preview?token=EAMB20sBAAA.tsbzRwFnTyQES0DzsnH33w.ERBzWG_40tvKbr7vm_nzLQ&postId=2519531318403595978&type=POST